# How to use norm.ppf() to find z values?

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I am new to python and I don't understand how to use the norm.ppf function to answer this question, can someone help me please?

Our professor gave us this line to help answer the homework:

```
import scipy.stats as stats
print(stats.norm.ppf( q=0.5-0.341, loc=0, scale=1))
```

The question asks about El Nino data in a standard normal distribution:
What ENSO index ε gives Pr(Z >= ε) = 0.1?

I'm completely baffled, how can I edit this code to answer the question?

Comment: Please include [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find an ε s.t.

```
P(Z >= ε) = 0.1 
=> 1- P(Z < ε) = 0.1 
=> P(Z < ε) = 0.9
```

Here, Z ~ N(0,1), a random variable following the standard normal distribution

The function `ppf()` is the quantile function, which is the the inverse of the `cdf()` function, that you can use to compute the value of ε for which the area under the standard normal curve to the left of Z=ε is going to be 0.9, using the following line of code:

```
ε = stats.norm.ppf(q=0.9, loc=0, scale=1)
ε
# 1.2815515655446004
```

Notice that the area under the curve to the left of the vertical line Z=ε will be = P(Z < ε) = Φ(ε) = 0.9 and can be found using the `cdf()` function as shown below:

```
stats.norm.cdf(ε, loc=0, scale=1)
# 0.89999999999999999
```

and the area under the curve to the right of Z=ε will be = P(Z >= ε) = 0.1.

You can see the same from the next plot:

```
z = np.linspace(-3,3,1000)
fz = stats.norm.pdf(z)
plt.plot(z, fz, label='f(z)')
plt.axvline(ε, color='red', label='z=ε')
plt.fill_between(z, fz, 0, where=z > ε)
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Here the shaded area under the curve, to the right of Z=ε=1.2815515655446004 has value 0.1